# How to customise scrollbar that apperas in mui Scroll bar

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, material-ui, autocomplete

I am Rendering a Autocomplete dropdown It has over 1000 values so, I get a scroll in the RHS of the options like very small blue slider, I want to make it a bit thick(increase the width) so it is visible and change the colour of the thumb In googled but found nothing on it so I Came here to get the info thank you in advance for heliping.

I tried to google it, To be honest I haven't tried much putting this here, so I can get help sooner if I havent found anything will update the solution as soon as I get or upVote the right answer. lines of code below

```
<Autocomplete value={value} fullWidth
        onChange={(event,newValue)=>{handleChange(newValue)}}
        getOptionLabel={(Options)=>`${Options.label}`}
        options={Options}
        isOptionEqualToValue={(option,value)=>option.label===value.label}
        inputValue={Ivalue}
        onInputChange={(event,newIvalue)=>{setIvalue(newIvalue)}}
        renderOption={(props,Options)=>(<Box component="li" {...props} key={Options.label}>{Options.label}</Box>)}
        renderInput={(params)=><TextField {...params} label="Search the combination" />} />
```

`